# How to ship an executable with Language.Haskell.Interpreter?

Tags: haskell, packaging

I was hoping to embed a Haskell interpreter using `hint` so that I could write plugins in Haskell to use with my program. I don't want to have to ship the entire Haskell platform for my executables.

Normally, Haskell executables are pretty self-contained. For example, erasing the `PATH` does not cause a problem:

```
$ PATH=. Hello
Hello world
```

However, a simple test program using `runInterpreter` bombs if I erase the `PATH`:

```
$ PATH=. TryHint
GhcException "panic! (the 'impossible' happened)\n  (GHC version 7.8.3 for x86_64-apple-darwin):\n\tDynamic linker not initialised\n\nPlease report this as a GHC bug:  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/reportabug\n"
```

**What libraries or executables have to be available in the environment for it to work?**

`otool` doesn't give much guidance:

```
otool -L TryHint
TryHint:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib (compatibility version 13.0.0, current version 13.0.0)
```

The test code for `TryHint` does not do much:

```
import Control.Monad
import Language.Haskell.Interpreter

main = do
  f <- runInterpreter $ loadModules ["Test"] >> setTopLevelModules ["Test"] >> interpret "f" (as :: Int -> Int)
  case f of
    Left e -> print e
    Right r -> mapM_ (print . r) [1..10]
```

It just binds `f` to a function in `Test.hs` to be interpreted at run-time. `Test.hs` looks like this:

```
module Test where
f :: Int -> Int
f x = x + 1
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. When I run `PATH= ./TryHint` everything goes smoothly: it prints a few numbers, then exits. I'm also using GHC 7.8.3. How are you building `TryHint`?

Comment: What about `PATH=. TryHint` (note where the space is)? The executable `TryHint` should be in the current working directory.

Comment: @user5402 I tried both. They're exactly the same.

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm just compiling the normal way with ghc. Starting to suspect it's actually an OSX-specific issue. Dynamic linking works differently from Linux in ways I don't understand.

Comment: I also believe it's likely to be specific to OSX. You might want to open a ticket at GHC's [tracker](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/report) as mentioned in the error message (after all, the impossible *did* just happen).

Comment: I have no idea what is going on with that error, but in any case GHC depends on a lot of resources which you are not hiding from it with `PATH=.`, such as the interface files for Prelude and everything it transitively imports, the actual library files for base and ghc-prim and integer-gmp, and the GHC `settings` file. (Basically, everything installed under `/usr/lib/ghc` or the equivalent directory for your installation.)

Comment: @ReidBarton I couldn't think of how to test it before but with `mv /usr/local/Cellar/ghc /usr/local/Cellar/ghc.bak` I get `/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.8.4/lib/ghc-7.8.4/settings: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`. I was hoping everything would be statically linked but it's not looking good.

Comment: @MichaelFox statically linking the GHC API doesn't work with the new dynamic linker introduced in GHC 7.8, I think :| (interactive code execution now requires dynamic libraries)

Comment: @bennofs it looks like your comment is almost an answer if you slightly reword it!

Comment: have you tried looking at the trace of system calls? It might help you find out where it hangs. In linux I would use strace, in OS X dtruss seems to be the equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Shipping an executable with `Language.Haskell.Interpreter` seems to go perfect with the way you have shown. You have to set your `PATH` to the script you want to execute.

And as of side note, as mentioned by @bennofs in comments, Statically linking the GHC API doesn't work with the new dynamic linker introduced in GHC 7.8, (interactive code execution now requires dynamic libraries).